# What is the link between anonymous credentials and transactional pseudonyms?

Tags: authentication, data-privacy

Anonymous credentials are used to prove certain properties of a specific user without revealing any other information, and transactional pseudonyms are used to authenticate a user as the rightful owner of a specific transaction without revealing any other information. Are transactional pseudonyms a form of anonymous credential, does anonymous credentials use transactional pseudonyms or are they distinct and unrelated?